# Alinhar textos ao centro começando do mesmo ponto

Tags: html, css

Queria saber como alinhar esses textos no centro e partindo do mesmo ponto.
Esta dúvida surgiu pois alinhei os textos ao centro da tela, mas queria que todos partissem do mesmo ponto no centro, para ficar todos alinhados e não formando esse tipo de "escadinha".
[Imagem de como está atualmente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFddM.png)

Código HTML:

```
        <div class="resume">
        <h1>Total de secretarias . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . <?php echo $total_sec ?></h1>
        <h1>Total de pastas digitalizadas . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . <?php echo $total_pastas ?></h1>
        <h1>Total de procedimentos digitalizados . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . <?php echo $total_proc ?></h1>
        </div>
```

Código CSS:

```
.resume{
margin-top: 20px;
flex-direction: column;
display: flex;
align-items: center;}

.resume h1{
color: #cbd0f7;
font-size: 18pt;}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá! tenta colocar os textos dentro de uma outra div, dentro de "resume". Assim você consegue deixar o "resume" no centro e na outra div mexer nas propriedades.

Ex:

```
<div class="resume">
    <div class="resume2">
        <h1>Total de secretarias . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . <?php echo $total_sec ?></h1>
        <h1>Total de pastas digitalizadas . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . <?php echo $total_pastas ?></h1>
        <h1>Total de procedimentos digitalizados . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . <?php echo $total_proc ?></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).